# Iterating each row with remaining rows in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, database, iterator, iteration

I am trying to iterate each row in dataframe with subsequent row.
The first iteration works but I want to iterate for all other iterations like [111,.....] with remaining and continues.
How can I achieve it using iterator?

```
test = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100],[111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1000],[1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,10000]]
df=pd.DataFrame(test)
row_iterator = df.iterrows()
_, main_row = next(row_iterator)
for i, row in row_iterator:
    print("---------Main Row-------------------")
    print(main_row)
    print("----------------------------")
    print("-----------Row-----------------")
    print(row)
    print("----------------------------")
    print("------------i----------------")
    print(i)
    print("----------------------------")
```

Comment: Please post what you are getting and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `next` these cases, a for loop "knows" how to deal with iterators.
Skip the `next`, just use the iterator directly:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(i, row)
```